# Find the lexicographically smallest order of N numbers such that the total of N numbers <= Threshold value

Tags: dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms, knapsack-problems, subset-sum, coin-change

GIven a number N, Threshold T and an array A. Find the lexicographically smallest order of N numbers from A such that the total of these N numbers is <= T.

This question is a simplification of [this dynamic programming question](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/tushars-birthday-bombs/):

> It’s Tushar’s birthday today and he has N friends. Friends are
>   numbered [0, 1, 2, …., N-1] and i-th friend have a positive strength
>   S(i). Today being his birthday, his friends have planned to give him
>   birthday bombs (kicks :P). Tushar’s friends know Tushar’s pain bearing
>   limit and would hit accordingly. If Tushar’s resistance is denoted by
>   R (>=0) then find the lexicographically smallest order of friends to
>   kick Tushar so that the cumulative kick strength (sum of the strengths
>   of friends who kicks) doesn’t exceed his resistance capacity and total
>   no. of kicks hit are maximum. Also note that each friend can kick
>   unlimited number of times (If a friend hits x times, his strength will
>   be counted x times)
>
> Example:
>
> R = 11, S = [6,8,5,4,7] Ans = [0,2]

Clearly, the maximum number of kicks = R/ min_element(S) = 11/4 = 2

So the question reduces to find the lexicographic smallest order of 2 elements in the Array such that the total of N elements is less than or equal to 11.

I am having a tough time thinking about a solution for this. Any leads/ ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track.

It turns out [the original question](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/tushars-birthday-bombs/) can be solved by a greedy algorithm. (A full blown solution by dynamic programming as I tried a while ago is both an overkill on coding and short of performance.)

Let us use the notation in the original question. $R$ is for the resistance capacity. $S$ is for the array of strengths.

Let the index of the first minimum strength be $m$. Then the maximum number of kicks is $n = R/S[m]$. So $O=[m, m, \cdots, m]$, where the number of $m$'s is $n$, is a kick order with maximum number of kicks, with total strength $n*S[m]$.

How can we get a lexicographically smaller order with the same number of kicks? If we can find an index $i$ smaller than $m$ such that we can replace a kick of strength $S[m]$ by a kick of strength $S[i]$ without overpassing the resistance capacity $R$, then we can replace the first element in $O$ by $i$, making the order lexicographically smaller. To make it as lexicographically as small as possible, we would like the index $i$ as small as possible and, then, we would like to use it as many times as possible.

For example, $R = 11, S = [6, 8, 5, 4, 7, 4]$. Then the first minimum strength is the first 4 whose index is 3. So $n=11/4=2$ and $O=[3,3]$ with total strength $4*2=8$. To make it smaller, we will check the strengths before 4 in order. The first one is $6$. Since $8-4+6=10<11$, we find a smaller order $[0,3]$. If we apply 6 again, we would get $10-4+6=12 > 11$. So we go ahead to check the next strength 8, which is too large. So we go ahead to check 5. Since $10-4+5=11\le 11$, we find a smaller order $[0,2]$. Since the room left for replacement, $11-11 =0$, we stop our effort. The final answer is [0,2].

I have verified that my program wrote along the above approach works. Hopefully, I have written enough to encourage you to go ahead. Hopefully, I have not written too much to spoil the fun for you.

This problem is a variation of [the unbounded knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have coded your solution and it works! I just have one final question: How did you come at this approach? Its brilliant! What was your thought process? How did you derive that this question could be solved via the Greedy way?

Comment: It is great that you get it to work. I arrived at the greedy way gradually and slowly. At first, I tried the dynamic programming as I am very familiar with that approach, which succeeded only partially because of its bad performance. Then I included your critical observation on the maximum number of kicks. Then I realized the impact of the lexicographical order.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA Implementation of the above approach by [Apaas.Jack](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/91753/apass-jack):-

```
public class Solution {
    public int sumDiff(ArrayList<Integer> ans, ArrayList<Integer> B,int A){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i<ans.size();i++){
            sum += B.get(ans.get(i));
        }
        return A-sum;
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> solve(int A, ArrayList<Integer> B) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int ind = -1;
        for (int i = 0;i<B.size();i++){
            if (min>B.get(i)){
                min = B.get(i);
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        int maxKicks = A/min;
        int temp = maxKicks;
        ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        if (maxKicks==0){
            return ans;
        }
        for (int i = 0;i<maxKicks;i++){
            ans.add(ind);
        }
        int sum = maxKicks*B.get(ind);
        for (int i = 0;i<ind;i++){
            if (sumDiff(ans,B,A)==0||temp==0){
                Collections.sort(ans);
                return ans;
            }
            while ((sum-B.get(ind)+B.get(i))<=A && temp != 0){
                ans.remove(0);
                ans.add(i);
                temp--;
                sum += (B.get(i)-B.get(ind));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(ans);
        return ans;     
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a programming site.

Answer (score -1):

`c++ solution

```
#define deb(x) cout<<#x<<" : "<<x<<"\n"
vector<int> Solution::solve(int A, vector<int> &B) {
map<int,int> s;

  for(int i=0;i<B.size();i++)
  if(s[B[i]]!=0)
  s[B[i]]=min(s[B[i]],i);
  else
  s[B[i]]=i;
  int idx=min_element(B.begin(),B.end())-B.begin();
  int mini=*min_element(B.begin(),B.end());
 int x=A/mini;
 vector<int> ans;
 for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
 ans.push_back(mini);
 int sum=mini*x;
 int j=0;
 for(int i=0;i<idx;i++)
  {  //  deb(sum);
   while(j<ans.size() && sum+B[i]-mini<=A)
   {
       ans[j]=B[i];
       sum=sum+B[i]-mini;
       //deb(sum);
       j++;
   }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<ans.size();i++)
  {
    ans[i]=s[ans[i]];    
   }
    return ans;

}
```

`

Comment: This site is more conceptual. Can you explain the algorithms in words or pseudocode instead of just providing code?